# PHPUnit require_once seemingly fails when running all tests when it gets to one specific file

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a directory full of test files with many tests in each test file. I added a new test file and from the command line "./phpunit-8.5.5.phar SupportTest.php" results in success for all tests within that file. When I want to run all of the tests with "./phpunit-8.5.5.phar ." I get an error regarding a global variable what appears to be a pre-load stage of PHPUnit (because none of the tests had run yet):

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myGlobalVariable in /Path/To/Tests/SupportTest.php on line 36

[tests would then run here, but I added an "exit" in the SupportTest.php file if the variable was not set so that I could debug this issue]

The variable "$myGlobalVariable" is set in a file that is included in SupportTest.php via 'require_once("../globals.inc");' If I check "isset($myGlobalVariable)", then it is NOT set when running all tests (.) but IS set when running the single test file (SupportTest.php). If I modify the code to "require" instead of "require_once" then that fails because the full directory test run already included "globals.inc" and a global function was already defined, so it fails on that:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare globalFunction() (previously declared...)

Is there some strange memory limit happening due to the addition of this one file? Why would PHPUnit lose the global variables yet believe it has included all of the global settings file (globals.inc)? There are a total of 504 tests spread across about 39 files.

Using Homebrew PHP 7.4, PHPUnit 8.5.5 (tried 8.5.22 with same failure)

Comment: Are you using really old code? I had to create some tests for SugarCRM 6 (that version is from 2012) a few weeks ago, and it was a pain you know where... I was not able to test some parts as it was using requires and not namespaces, also using global variables and it is extremely complex to unit test... could you share more info? What are you trying to test? Is it your own framework?

Comment: I am testing my own code which is pretty basic PHP. It has some classes but otherwise a lot more like looking at C code. The test files were originally written around the time of PHPUnit 3 and all subsequent ones follow a similar structure. I'm not very familiar with namespaces, so I'm assuming the code is what you would call really old.

Comment: Yes, if you are not using namespaces, then the code could be really old, it depends on which PHP version you are using. I would personally say that anything before PHP 5.6 ( PHP <= 5.5) is really old. [Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) were added on PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.3 is from July 2009... If you have a look at any modern framework like [Laravel 5.1](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/composer.json) (that is a really old version) it was already using Namespaces and it required PHP >= 5.5.9. If you are using `global variables`, then you are not using DI

Comment: Just to clarify, all of the code runs without PHP errors or warnings (PHP 7.4). I keep on top of deprecations and resolve them. However, in this particular case PHPUnit appears to cause the Notice of undefined variable but only for this file and only when running all tests (./phpunit .).

Comment: I am not sure about that error. I had a similar issue and I was able to solve it by just using a `bootstrap.php` file declared on the `phpunit.xml`. I just did `global $variable` (`$variable` should be your variables that you need). After doing so the variables were available inside my tests (because PHPUnit uses namespaces, you need to still use global, but it is a total pain to mix `global` and `namespaces`).